# DbUpdateExecption- An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Got a problem with my Asp.net Mvc4 application.

I designed a "User" Table and a "Projectable" and there is a many-to-many-relationship.

My User Table:

```
 public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Role = new HashSet<Role>();
        this.Project = new HashSet<Project>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Project { get; set; }
}
```

And my Project Table:

```
public partial class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        this.Thresholds = new HashSet<Thresholds>();
        this.User = new HashSet<User>();
        this.Testrelease = new HashSet<Testrelease>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Thresholds> Thresholds { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Testrelease> Testrelease { get; set; }
}
```

In my Project-Controller :

```
public ActionResult EditProject(int id = 0)
    {
        Project project = db.Project.Find(id);
        if (project == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        List<CheckBoxListInfoInt> userCheck = new List<CheckBoxListInfoInt>();
        foreach (User U in db.User.ToList())
        {
            userCheck.Add(new CheckBoxListInfoInt
            {
                ValueInt = U.Id,
                DisplayText = U.Username,
                IsChecked = (project.User.Contains(U))
            });
        }
        ViewBag.P_usrCB = userCheck;
        ViewData["pid"] = id;
        return View(project);
    }

    //
    // POST: /KPI_Data/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditProject(Project project)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Project.Attach(project);

            db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;

            if (project.User.Count > 0)
                project.User.Clear();


            List<string> usrlist = new List<string>();
            var ucb = Request.Form["P_usrCB"];
            if (ucb != null)
                foreach (string item in ucb.Split(','))
                {
                    int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(item);
                    User usr = db.User.Single(x => x.Id == UserId);
                    project.User.Add(usr);
                    usrlist.Add(usr.Username);
                }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(project);
    }
```

The error occurs at

> db.SaveChanges();

in my HttpPost ActionMethod

Error Message is :

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

Why do I get this error? and what is the solution? thx

Comment: Check your properties on foreign keys mappings

Answer (score -1):

Avoid `db.Entry(ptvm.place).State = EntityState.Modified;` as it causes concurrency conflicts with no updation. Use ViewModel for a many-many relation rather than two tables.

You must use `UpdateModel(table object, "model");`

Full Example is as belows :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PlaceTag(PlacesWithTagsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       tag tagtest = GetTagById(model.tagid);
       tag.name= model.tag.name;
       tag.nameplural = model.tag.nameplural;
       UpdateModel(tag, "model");
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { id = 5 });
    } 
}
```

The advantage of UpdateModel is that you have to mention only those fields which you update avoiding those which remain static. In this way you can update your related data with Viewmodel in Edit View.